# What is the documentation convention in python for a parameter which is optional only when another parameter is used

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have a function `create_person` which creates a person object, now let's say I want to give the user the option to either call it with `create_person('Tomer', 19, ...)` or with `create_person(base_person=tomer_person, ...)`, how should I document this behavior properly? is this a correct way to define a function?

Example:

```
def create_person(name=None, age=None, base_person=None):
    if not name and not age and base_person:
        person = base_person
    elif not base_person:
        person = Person(name, age)
    ...
```

Comment: I think it would be better to modify the `constructor` of the `Person` class itself to provide that feature. Although what you're doing looks okay too.

Comment: @ghost this is a simplified example of my problem, unfortunately I can't access the constructor of the class so I need to resort to this kind of solution.

Comment: You could inherit the class and overwrite the constructor.

Comment: @Dschoni Sorry, I wasn't clear enough in my previous answer, I need this kind of function (if this is a proper function declaration in python) for the structure I am working with it..

Comment: The function definition is proper. You do have three kwargs. To document if they are optional it depends on your documentation style. I personaly use `numpydoc` and would therefore document `base_person` as being optional if the other two are not given.

Comment: @Dschoni would you mind providing a full example of how you would document this function?

Comment: Why not provide two functions?

Comment: @Wombatz This is inspired by TensorFlow `.fit` function which used to be two functions (`.fit` and `.fit_generator`) but they were combined into `.fit` which accepts this kind of structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `numpydoc` style, one possible way would be:

```
def create_person(name=None, age=None, base_person=None):
    r"""A function to create a person.

    Using this function, a person can be created using
    either a combination of `name` and `age` or providing a `base_person`.

    Parameters
    ----------
    name : int [optional, default=None]
        The name of the person to be created. Leave this as None to create a person
        using the `base_person` keyword.
    age : int [optional, default=None]
        The age of the person to be created. Leave this as None to create a person
        using the `base_person` keyword. 
    base_person : instance of Person class [optional, default=None]
        If `age` and `name` are None, this keyword can be used to create a person
        from an instance of the `Person` class."""
```

Personally, I would create two different functions, one creating a person by name and age, and one using a `base_person` object. Internally they could call the function you provided with the correct caller signature. E.g:

```
def create_person_explicit(name, age):
    return(create_person(name=name, age=age)

def create_person_from_object(base_person):
    return(create_person(base_person=base_person)
```

It's a little hard to tell what exactly is the right solution for your exact problem as too much information is missing.

Comment: Thank you! I think this answered my question completely.

Comment: I added the `[optional, default...]` to `base_person` as well.

Comment: Also note, that the `[optional..]` bracket is not part of the official standard but rather my personal style.